# Anonymous controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently learning to test with rspec (ruby on rails) (it's safe to assume I know very little), and am a bit stuck when it comes to testing with anonymous controllers. I tried googling it, but I feel like it doesn't give me what I'm looking for. So basically, what is an anonymous controller and why (or when) do I want one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you've read the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) and found it unsatisfactory?

Comment: FWIW, I have never used this feature (in all my ~10 years of ruby). But I also think that testing controllers is (mostly) a waste of resources. YMMV.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - yes, I found that unsatisfactory. Maybe it's because my overall understanding of the testing environment is not intuitive enough.

Comment: Do anonymous controllers "create" the controller with its actions or what does it do?

Comment: They allow subclassing your existing controller for easier test setup. For example, you can redefine your `show` action to always raise RecordNotFound exception and your test will verify that relevant text is displayed on the page (or that it redirests to correct location, or something else like that)

Comment: Thanks. I'll ponder that a bit

Answer (score 2):

The main reason you would want to use an anonymous controller  is that you are developing reusable library code (a gem) thats meant to plug into any arbitrary controller.

For example this base controller class to dry the common CRUD boilerplate code:

```
module MyGem
  class ResourcefulController < ::ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_resource, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def show
    end

    private

    def derive_resource_class_name
      self.class.name.demodulize.chomp('Controller').singularize
    end

    def resource_class
      derive_resource_class_name.constantize
    end

    def set_resource
      @resource = resource_class.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

The normal way of testing this would require that we create a controller and a route just for the test itself.

By using an anonymous controller we can get around that:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyGem::ResourcefulController, type: :controller do
  controller do
    def show
      render plain: @resource
    end
  end
  before do
    model = Class.new do
      def self.find(id)
        "You found me"
      end
    end
    stub_const("Resourceful", model)
  end
  it "derives the resource class from the name of the controller" do
    get :show, params: { id: 1 }
    expect(response.body).to eq "You found me"
  end
end
```

RSpec also cleverly creates stub routes for the normal CRUD actions.

But for normal Rails application code its not very useful at all - parent classes (or included modules) are better tested by creating a request or feature spec that covers the actual behaviour in the end product. This lets you create a failing spec, get to green and then refactor.

Comment: Found your solution, while I was looking for something like for a Controller Concern. Ended up defining a class_method to explicitly provide the symbol of the class, but I liked your implementation !